# Mimetype error in django-react production

Tags: reactjs, django

I've setup react inside django.

in `settings.py`

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR.joinpath('frontend', 'build', 'static'),
]

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR.joinpath('frontend'),
        ],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]
```

in `views.py`

```
def index_view(request):
    return render(request, 'build/index.html')
```

in `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path('.*', views.index_view, name='index'),
]
```

got

```
Refused to apply style from 'https://example.com/static/css/main.e6c13ad2.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
vpn.ipractus.com/:1 Refused to execute script from 'https://example.com/static/js/main.c459ef9d.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

Comment: if you access this url https://example.com/static/css/main.e6c13ad2.css, what is the return? 404? and have you run collectstatic?

Comment: No 200. Returns fine. But problem is not showing

Comment: I think the return is should css or js response code, not HTML page, because clearly the message says the return is HTML type "because its MIME type ('text/html')"

Comment: want to run react-create-app project